# C++ Polymorphism does not work as it should in Code::Blocks 17.12

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I learned C++ using the Code::Blocks. However, the compiler gives me an error in the file Daughter.h, line 6, saying `"error: expected-class name before '{' token"` when I am trying to implement the inheritance. That confuses me more because the tutorial I'm watching using Code::Blocks and compiler in this tutorial does not gives any errors, it in fact works perfectly. I am a bit frustrated at this point. Does anybody know how to make it work? Here are all of my files:

**main.cpp**

```
//main.cpp
#include "Daughter.h"
#include "Mother.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mother jelo;
    jelo.sayname();
    Daughter tina;
    tina.sayname();
}
```

**Mother.h**

```
//Mother.h
#ifndef MOTHER_H
#define MOTHER_H


class Mother
{
    public:
        Mother();
        void sayname();
};

#endif // MOTHER_H
```

**Mother.cpp**

```
//Mother.cpp
#include "Daughter.h"
#include "Mother.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Mother::Mother()
{
}

void Mother::sayname() {

    cout << "I am Roberts" << endl;

}
```

**Daughter.h**

```
//Daughter.h
#ifndef DAUGHTER_H
#define DAUGHTER_H


class Daughter: public Mother
{
    public:
        Daughter();
};

#endif // DAUGHTER_H
```

**Daughter.cpp**

```
//Daughter.cpp
#include "Daughter.h"
#include "Mother.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Daughter::Daughter()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daughter.h should `#include "Mother.h"`, because it needs to know what `Mother` is.

If the tutorial doesn't say that, the tutorial is wrong.

Learn C++ from [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/560648), instead.